# Can you recommend JavaScript grid?

Tags: javascript, grid

Which JavaScript grid (jQuery-based is preferred) have all of the following:
- several upper rows and left columns freezing
- cell merging
- in-place multiline cell editing
- multicolumn sorting and filtering
- insertion and deletion of rows and columns
- ease of code modification and extension

If it has these properties "out of the box" without needing to work with code it'll be additional plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/)?  It is fully feature with great documentation

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but I just wanted to leave a note here as well if someone ends up here using the search.

You should check out <v-grid>, which is a top-notch javascript grid component. It’s part of Vaadin Components: http://www.vaadin.com/components